# How to make a regex expression for this content?

Tags: regex

I am scraping a website which looks like this, and I am looking for `4 /  5` and `3 /  10`. That is, I want `(number) + space + slash +  3 spaces + another number.`

I tried the regex expression `^[0-9]+(\/[0-9]+)"  *"*$` but that did not work.

```
<td>Monday</td>
<td class="text-center text-danger font-weight-bold">4 /  5</td>
</td>
<td>Tuesday</td>
<td class="text-center text-danger font-weight-bold">3 /  10</td>
</td>
```

Comment: Generally: `\d+\s+/\s+\d+` ... BTW you seem to have _two_ spaces on the right side, not three.

Comment: It seems like you are attempting to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Generally, this is not something meant to be solved using regex. Consider using a HTML parser for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Use word boundary `\b` instead of `^` and `$`, because the text you are looking for is somewhere in the middle of your text. This regex should work:

```
/\b[0-9]+ +\/ +[0-9]+\b/
```

The  `+` makes the regex more forgiving, by requiring at least one space.

If you want to capture the numbers separately you can introduce capture groups, to reference them with `$1` and `$2`, respectively:

```
/\b([0-9]+) +\/ +([0-9]+)\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep "[[:digit:]]\{1,\} \/  [[:digit:]]\{1,\}" filename
<td class="text-center text-danger font-weight-bold">4 /  5</td>
<td class="text-center text-danger font-weight-bold">3 /  10</td>
$
```

You have started the regex with `^` which is to anchor the regex to beginning of line.

Comment: Using `grep -E -e '[[:digit:]]+ /  [[:digit:]]+'` simplifies things a bit.  GNU `grep` has an option `-o` to show just the matched material; that could be useful too.